# perl: print with space between function call

Tags: perl, printing

```
use strict;

sub main {
    print shift;
    nested(@_);
}

sub nested {
    print shift;
    deep(@_);
}

sub deep {
    print shift;
}

my @list = qw(main nested deep);
main(@list);
```

How to get this "stair-step" output:

```
>main
>>nested
>>>deep
```

**Note** functions main, nested and deep - required and may be call over and over in different variations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd generally pass around an indentation string, along these lines:

```
use strict;

sub main {
    my ($strings, $indent) = @_;
    $indent = "" unless defined $indent;
    print $indent, shift(@$strings), "\n";
    nested($strings, $indent."\t");
}

sub nested {
    my ($strings, $indent) = @_;
    $indent = "" unless defined $indent;
    print $indent, shift(@$strings), "\n";
    deep($strings, $indent."\t");
}

sub deep {
    my ($strings, $indent) = @_;
    $indent = "" unless defined $indent;
    print $indent, shift(@$strings), "\n";
}

my @list = qw(main nested deep);
main(\@list);
```

A similar technique is to pass around an indent level as an integer, incrementing it as needed:

```
use strict;

sub main {
    my ($strings, $indent) = @_;
    $indent = 0 unless defined $indent;
    print "\t" x $indent, shift(@$strings), "\n";
    nested($strings, $indent+1);
}

sub nested {
    my ($strings, $indent) = @_;
    $indent = 0 unless defined $indent;
    print "\t" x $indent, shift(@$strings), "\n";
    deep($strings, $indent+1);
}

sub deep {
    my ($strings, $indent) = @_;
    $indent = 0 unless defined $indent;
    print "\t" x $indent, shift(@$strings), "\n";
}

my @list = qw(main nested deep);
main(\@list);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your array is a list of subroutine names that you want to be called in order. To do that you need to disable `strict 'refs'` temporarily. This example demonstrates.

Note that the code for all three subroutines is identical. Presumably you will want to put something between the `print` trace output and the call to the next subroutine in the list the differentiates the three blocks of code.

I have written it so that the number of preceding angle brackets is passed as the second parameter to the subroutines, and defaults to 1 if no value was passed (for the initial call of the sequence).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @list = qw(main nested main deep nested);
main(\@list);

sub main {
  my ($list, $indent) = (@_, 1);
  my $name = shift @$list;
  print '>' x $indent, $name, "\n";

  no strict 'refs';
  &{$list->[0]}($list, $indent + 1) if @$list;
}

sub nested {
  my ($list, $indent) = (@_, 1);
  my $name = shift @$list;
  print '>' x $indent, $name, "\n";

  no strict 'refs';
  &{$list->[0]}($list, $indent + 1) if @$list;
}

sub deep {
  my ($list, $indent) = (@_, 1);
  my $name = shift @$list;
  print '>' x $indent, $name, "\n";

  no strict 'refs';
  &{$list->[0]}($list, $indent + 1) if @$list;
}
```

**output**

```
>main
>>nested
>>>main
>>>>deep
>>>>>nested
```

Comment: Thanks! Very interesting.
My list is tokenzier output. Like in this lesson http://nand2tetris.org/10.php

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to maintain the indent level in it's own state:

```
sub decorator {

    my $string = +shift;
    my $level = 0;

    return sub { $string x ++$level }
}

my $steps = decorator( '>' );  # Each time $steps->() is called
                               # the indent level increases

print $steps->(), $_, "\n" for qw( main deep nested );
```